# Calling Active Directory user window

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to create a C# task that takes a domain and username as arguments and then pops up the Active Directory user window from that.

If dsa.msc takes parameters to do it then it's fine too. I found this:
https://www.petri.com/forums/forum/microsoft-networking-services/active-directory/43304-starting-ad-mmc-consoles-focused-on-a-particular-domain-or-dc-was-someone-help
So it seems like dsa.msc are able to pass in arguments, but I cannot find help on this and if it's possible to go all the way to the user.

[image: I want to pop up this DSA.msc User window]

Found https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker but that does not give me this dialogbox.

Thanks

Comment: Your user probably doesn't know anything.

Comment: yep - he knows nothing :)